# Slick postgresql json: how to make case insensitive search?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, slick

I have json column in postgresql mapped to JsValue in slick model.

```
case class Product(id: EntityId, name: JsValue)    

class Products(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Product](tag, "products") {
  def name        = column[JsValue]("name")

  def * =
    (id, name) <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)
}
```

I can perform search inside json column using slick-pg library
(https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg)

`val nameFilter: JsValue = Json.obj("en" -> name)
products.filter(_.name @> nameFilter).result.headOption`

But problem is that PostgreSql is case sensitive, and I need to perform a case-insensitive search within `name.en`

I cannot use `toLowerCase` slick extension (like `_.name.toLowerCase`) since `name` is JsValue

Is there any way to perform a case-insensitive search within json columns with slick?